# Register additional wp plugin directory

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, directory, paths

I'm trying to register a subfolder as a plugin path, where my company would keep it's own plugins (e.g. **wp-content/plugins/company-name/**). I've already found, how to redefine the plugin path with `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`, but I only want to add an additional one. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Don't. Just prefix all your plugins with company- in the folder names and keep them where WP (and developers) expect them to be.

Comment: @janh it seemed for us sensitive, so as to let us add our git repository with plugins as a submodule to our projects and in case we update any plugin, we could just recursively update all projects that use it.

Comment: I'd rather go the WP way. Look into private plugin repositories, and update the WP way, which will also run the appropriate hooks (to make sure potentially required DB schema updates run as well). And then maybe something like InfiniteWP to centralize plugin/theme update management. We're still using git for development, but never to pull from inside a live site.

Answer (score 0):

If they're important you could take a look at [Must-use plugins.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)
They can't be disabled from the backend.

Answer (score -2):

Just redefine your `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` in `wp-config.php` file:

```
define("WP_PLUGIN_DIR", "your plugin path");
```